# How can I add the css to my project asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm making a project Asp.net mvc and I found a free css template and I trying to add to my project but I don't get successful Result.

In the folder "Content" I have the files css.

In the forder "View/Shared" I have a _Layout.cshtml with this code in the head
`<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You should add additional information here. Please post the head of the `_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content") 
  
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
    <section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <p>Copyright W3schools 2012. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can add a new css file in your _Layout.cshtml view.

```
<head>
...
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSSFileName.css")" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

You probably need to see if the .css file you're using matches the classes you have in your existing project.

Comment: I put it like this but it doesn' work

Comment: Can you post the relevant .css file you want to use?

Comment: `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Content/css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>`

Answer (score 2):

You can just put the links in the Layout.cshtml file located in the Shared Folder. Like this or you can look at bundling. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

```
<head>
   <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
   <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: I do this but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the _Layout.cshtml file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my _Layout.cshtml and css too

```css
body
{
font: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: red;
color: #696969;
}
h1
{
border-bottom: 3px solid #cc9900;
font: Georgia, serif;
color: #996600;
}
#main
{
padding: 20px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
}
a
{
color: #034af3; 
}
/* Menu Styles ------------------------------*/ 
ul#menu
{
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li
{
display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a 
{
background-color: #e8eef4;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
/*CSS3 properties*/
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a:hover
{
background-color: #ffffff;
} 
/* Forms Styles ------------------------------*/ 
fieldset
{
padding-left: 12px;
} 
fieldset label
{
display: block;
padding: 4px;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
width: 300px;
}
input[type="submit"]
{
padding: 4px;
}
/* Data Styles ------------------------------*/ 
table.data
{
background-color:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%;
}
table.data th
{
background-color:#e8eef4;
border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
padding:3px;
}
table.data td 
{
border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
padding:3px;
}
```

```html
        
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="~/Content/css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
  
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
    <section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <p>Copyright W3schools 2012. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </section>

   
</body>
</html>
```